# Converting data types in columns and replacing NaN and other values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, types, nan

I've got [this dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdovU.png) in pandas with NaN and "Unknown" values in some cells and with "object" data type of all the columns. I am to get rid of this troubling values (dropping lines is forbidden), and to change the column types into appropriate ones. I've tried this code:

```
import numpy as np
movies_converted = movies.copy()
movies_converted.replace(to_replace='Unknown', value=np.nan, regex=True)
movies_converted.fillna("", inplace=True)
movies_converted['Title']=movies_converted['Title'].astype('str')
movies_converted['US Gross']=pd.to_numeric(movies_converted['US Gross'],errors='coerce').astype('int') 
movies_converted['Worldwide Gross']=pd.to_numeric(movies_converted['Worldwide Gross'], errors='coerce').astype('int')
movies_converted['Production Budget']=pd.to_numeric(movies_converted['Production Budget']).astype('int')
movies_converted['Release Date']=pd.to_datetime(movies_converted['Release Date'],errors='coerce')
movies_converted['Distributor']=movies_converted['Distributor'].astype('str')
movies_converted['Source']=movies_converted['Source'].astype('str')
movies_converted['Major Genre']=movies_converted['Major Genre'].astype('str')
movies_converted['Creative Type']=movies_converted['Creative Type'].astype('str')
movies_converted['Director']=movies_converted['Director'].astype('str')
movies_converted['Rotten Tomatoes Rating']=pd.to_numeric(movies_converted['Rotten Tomatoes Rating'])
movies_converted['IMDB Rating']=movies_converted['IMDB Rating'].str.replace(',',".").astype('float', errors='ignore')
movies_converted['IMDB Votes']=pd.to_numeric(movies_converted['IMDB Votes'],errors='coerce')
movies_converted
```

I'm new to Python, so I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but I always get some errors, now it's this one "ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer". Please, give some advice about the best ways to do my work and about my mistakes.

Comment: You have replaced values with `""` how can these be converted to integers? That integer will the be equal to? That's why you are getting that error.

Comment: and how can I fix this in my case without dropping?

Comment: you should use `pd.to_numeric` with `errors='coerce'` to convert numeric-like columns with bad data to a numeric dtype. Now those will all become `float` since normal `int` dtypes can't store `NaN`, but you can try out the `'Int64'` dtype if you really want `1` instead of `1.0` Though small ints can be stored precisely as float64, so I often don't bother.

Comment: @ALollz wow thank you, it worked, but now I've got other problems..I don't understand why converting into strings didn't work and why columns "Rotten Tomatoes Rating" and "IMDB Votes" again have NaN values, though the others don't. The picture for better understanding of the situation: https://ibb.co/FhwrMGx